# Automorphisms of weighted quiver

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, quivers, cluster-algebras

I am reading this paper [strongly primitiv species with potentials I : mutations](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.3495.pdf).

In page 6, they give the definition of weighted quiver:  a weighted quiver is a pair $(Q,d)$, where $Q$ is a loop-free quiver and $d=(d_i)_{i \in Q_0}$ is a tuple that assigns a positive integer $d_i$ to each vertex $i$ of $Q$.

They also give the morphisms between the corresponding path algebras. But I have not found the definition of morphisms between weighted quivers, or automorphisms of weighted quivers.

Is there any references or works that give a definition of automorphisms of weighted quiver? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Path algebras are algebras, so there's a natural desire to look at (homo)morphisms between those algebras.  (Weighted) quivers are graphs, so one could define morphisms between them, along the same lines that one would normally define morphisms of graphs - functions on the vertex sets respecting the edge structure (there are choices to be made in such a definition).  But what would you want to do with such a morphism? For what purpose do you want an automorphism of a weighted quiver?

Comment: @Jan Grabowski  I want to do something about the orbit quiver of the weighted quivers under some special automorphisms.(for example, let $Q$ be a ordinary quiver, G is an automorphism group, we define $Q_G$ the orbit quiver such that the vertexes are $Gx$ for $x$ vertex of $Q$ and the arrows are $Ga$ for $a$ arrows of $Q$) But I can not found a specific definition of automorphisms of weighted quiver, also get stuck in how to define the weight of the orbit quiver.

Comment: The first thing will presumably be to decide whether weights have to be preserved.  But then only quivers with at least two vertices of the same weight can possibly have non-trivial automorphisms, and even these might not have any, if the weights are on "incompatible" vertices.  On the plus side, though, if a "weighted quiver automorphism" has to preserve weights, the weight of a vertex of $Q_{G}$ will be well-defined.

Comment: @Jan Grabowski If weights have to be preserved between vertexes of the same orbit, I think there will be very little automorphisms. I prefer not preserving the weights. Also as you say, the weight of $Q_G$ is a question. Still thank you for your help.